# convert pascal to c++, i do not know about pascal

Tags: c++, pascal

```
PBYTE(inAddr)^ := $E8;
PDWORD(inAddr + 1)^ := rMemAddr - inAddr - 5;
```

I need convert code to c++, but i do not know about Pascal, pls help me, thanks！

I tryed, but the two line code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess I would say

```
*(uint8_t*)inAddr = 0xE8;
*(uint32_t*)(inAddr + 1) = rMemAddr - inAddr - 5;
```

I do remember that `^` is the indirection operator in Pascal and `:=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: thak you very much ! my friend.

Comment: @john What you showed will work, but you should be using C++-style casts instead: `*reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(inAddr) = 0xE8; *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(inAddr + 1) = rMemAddr - inAddr - 5;` Also, `PBYTE` and `PDWORD` are [Win32 API types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), so if the code is compiled for Windows (which is likely the case if the Pascal code came from Delphi), you can use `PBYTE` and `PDWORD` as-is in the casts, eg: `*reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(inAddr) = 0xE8; *reinterpret_cast<PDWORD>(inAddr + 1) = rMemAddr - inAddr - 5;`